# Ruby - cant divide with fixnum values

Tags: ruby, math, fixnum

I need to calculate some % values by dividing two separate counts. I got the counts value which is class is fixnum. But while i am going to divide them, it showing me 0 whatever the count value is ,

```
<% dueTask = 12 %>
<% aT = 16 %>
<%= (dueTask/aT)*.to_f %>
```

Here Last result showing 0.

Comment: Any one operand should be float type, arithmetic operation returns float type.

Comment: duetask.to_f/aT => some value of float type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two different lines in order to get the actual value.

```
    <% dueTask = 12 %>
    <% aT = 16 %>
    <% result = dueTask/aT.to_f %>
    <%= result %>
```

In IRB you can get the value by checking this:

```
dueTask = 12
aT = 16
dueTask/aT.to_f
```

but this technique might not work when you have to show the result in HTML. the variables are of Fixnum type (you can check it by the following command in IRB shell)

```
dueTask.class
```

Output will be

```
#=> Fixnum
```

Comment: ,thanks bro, i got my solution. thing is i need to convert fixnum into float.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. In your case you are dividing a Fixnum by a Float.

Comment: @CedricH. Any one operand should be float type, arithmetic operation returns float type. Answer is not misleading.

Comment: @AlokAnand It is misleading. "Dividing Fixnum with another Fixnum requires to call to_f method in order to get fraction value." the point is that you should not divide a fixnum by a fixnum .

Comment: @AlokAnand I agree that you second block of code works. But does the first one give the expected result? I don't see how it could.

Comment: @CedricH. a/b.to_f == a.to_f/b
 => true  
 a.to_f/b == a.to_f/b.to_f
 => true

Comment: @AlokAnand I don't see how that relates to my remark. We both understood that. Nevertheless your answer is still terribly unclear: if the first block works, you don't explain why and your last sentence is not as clear as your last comment.

Comment: @CedricH. here I agree with code in answer, but I do not agree with last line "Dividing Fixnum with another Fixnum requires to call to_f method in order to get fraction value."

Comment: @CedricH. anyhow, a.to_f.class => Float, so I said any one operand should be of float type to get result of float type in arithmetic operation. If any one operand is wider than Fixnum, result of arithmetic operation involving that operand is wider than Fixnum.

Comment: @AlokAnand Your last line is the core of the answer. Yet it is misleading: dividing a fixnum by another fixnum gives a fixnum. So at least one as to be cast into a float first.

Comment: @AlokAnand So we both agree: the answer is misleading. Your (the) main point is totally absent from the answer.

Comment: answer has been corrected. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @CedricH. Now I understood why Switzerland is beautiful. :)

Comment: @AlokAnand Actually I'm not Swiss, just living there and sometimes it can be painful, I wanted to share the feeling :p

Comment: @CedricH. Life is always a struggle, I am from India only and stay in Bangalore to work and it is 2.5 thousand Km away from my native :( Anyhow Indian public wonder why Switzerland allows corrupt Indian politicians to stash their black money there.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert them to float before division:

```
(dueTask.to_f/aT.to_f)
```

otherwise you'll get only integer part of the division, which is `0` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The way you did it the division is done with to integer, so the result is an integer. Even if you convert it to a float you just convert the result (0 in this case).

So you need to convert at least one of the two integers into a float:

```
<% dueTask = 12 %> 
<% aT = 16 %> 
<%= (dueTask.to_f/aT) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are getting the right answer to that division `0`, because you are dividing 2 numbers that act as integer, and therefore you will get an integer answer.

To get a **decimal** answer from the division you need to convert them to float and then do the division.

```
dueTask.to_f/aT.to_f
```

Your code will end up like this:

```
<% dueTask = 12 %>
<% aT = 16 %>
<%= (dueTask.to_f/aT.to_f) %>
```